# My Ethereum Wallet/Mist Stuck after Byzantium update

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp, clients

After updating my ethereum wallet and mist now they are stuck at around block 4,375,146. It actually keeps downloading new block but never goes up to the latest block (always +4000 block behind... and it has been like that since yesterday) Also some of my balances do not show real or current values.

What can I do to sync totally with the network? I´m running a iMac, macOS Sierra

Comment: I too am having problems since the fork. was stuck at 4,370,000. all values not accurate either in my wallets. scary stuff

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13443)

Comment: Have the same problem , stuck at the same block 4 370 000 :-) Funny

Answer (score -1):

At block 4,370,000 was the Byzantinum fork ([Byzantium HF Announcement](https://blog.ethereum.org/2017/10/12/byzantium-hf-announcement/) by Ethereum team). You should update Ethereum Wallet to a [new version](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases). So they will update the blockchain to the fork.